# explaining $|a+b|≤|a|+|b|$ in simple terms

Tags: inequality, triangles

I'm struggling to get to grips with the Triangle Inequalities. The problem is I don't really understand what it means. This is what my lecturer has written in the notes:
$$
|a+b|≤|a|+|b|.
$$
First of all, I don't understand why it's less than or equal to.

If I plug in numbers, for example $a=2$ and $b=5$, I struggle to see how $|2+5|≤|2|+|5|$.

If someone could explain this to me I would be very grateful.

Comment: $|2+5|=7=|2|+|5|$

Comment: Less than or equal to means that either $|a+b|<|a|+|b|$ or $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$. If $a=2$ and $b=5$, then $|2+5|=|2|+|5|$, but it is also true that $|2+5|\le|2|+|5|$.

Comment: If you plug in -2 and 5 instead, you'll see it immediately

Answer (score 10):

OK. I will try to explain why
$$
|a+b|\leq |a| + |b|
$$
is true in a somewhat intuitive/pictorial way.

First off, do you know what $|x|$ **means** for some number $x$? You probably know that $|x|$ means the *absolute value* of $x$, but what does *that* even mean? The absolute value of a number $x$ may be thought of as its "absolute" distance from zero on the real number line. For example, how far away is $3$ from $0$? This is clearly $3$ units away. What about $-4$? Well, this is just $4$ units away from $0$ but in a different direction (remember, the only thing that matters is *absolute* distance and distances are always positive). Thus, we get the following definition for the absolute value of a number $x$:
$$
|x|=
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if} & x\geq 0,\\
-x &\text{if} & x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
This guarantees us that the distance from $x$ to $0$ will always be positive, regardless of the value of $x$.

Phew. Okay. Now consider what $|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$ **means**. What if $a$ is positive and $b$ is negative? What number will be larger: $|a+b|$ or $|a|+|b|$? Can you see how this might confirm the truth of the triangle inequality?

If you need more explanation or want a general proof (although I think a general proof may confuse you more than help you at the moment), then let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you supply two arbitrary real numbers $a$ and $b$. Let's construct a "triangle" (on the number line) whose vertices are $0$, $a$, and $-b$. (We're free to choose vertices as we like; pick $-b$ instead of $b$ for reasons to be explained in a moment.)

Since the distance between real number $x$ and $y$ is $|x - y|$, the sides of our "triangle" have lengths
$$
|a - 0| = |a|,\qquad
|-b - 0| = |-b| = |b|,\qquad
|a - (-b)| = |a + b|.
$$
(Now you know why we picked $-b$: To get $a + b$ inside the absolute value.:)

Two sides of our triangle have length $|a|$ and $|b|$. It's reasonable to ask: *Based on this information alone, how long can the third side be?*

It should be fairly clear geometrically that:

- The third side cannot exceed $|a| + |b|$, the sum of the lengths of the known sides. In symbols,
  $$
  |a + b| \leq |a| + |b|.
  $$
  This is the *triangle inequality*.
- The third side cannot be shorter than the distance between the real numbers $|a|$ and $|b|$. In symbols
  $$
  |a + b| \geq \bigl||a| - |b|\bigr|.
  $$
  This is the *reverse triangle inequality*.

In your particular example, if two sides of a triangle have length $2$ and $5$, then the third side cannot be shorter than $|2 - 5| = |-3| = 3$, and cannot be longer than $|2 + 5| = |7| = 7$. (On the number line, the sides of a "triangle" are parallel, so the third side is actually *equal* either to $3$ or to $7$. However, similar-looking inequalities hold for distance in the plane, or in space, or in higher-dimensional spaces. In these spaces, the sides of a triangle need not be parallel. In the plane, the third side of your triangle could have any length between $3$ and $7$.)

[image: The triangle and reverse triangle inequalities]

---

One nice proof of the triangle inequalities (for real numbers) is to show that if $x$ and $c$ are real numbers, then $|x| \leq c$ if and only if $-c \leq x \leq c$. (That is, an upper bound on the absolute value of $x$ can be "traded" for a *symmetric pair* of upper and lower bounds on $x$.)

Clearly,
\begin{align*}
-|a| &\leq a \leq |a| &&\text{for all real $a$,} \\
-|b| &\leq b \leq |b| &&\text{for all real $b$.} \\
\text{ Adding,}\quad
-\bigl(|a| + |b|\bigr) &\leq a + b \leq |a| + |b|. &&
\end{align*}
The third line has the form $-c \leq x \leq c$ for $x = a + b$ and $c = |a| + |b|$, and so can be "traded" for $|x| \leq c$, namely, for
$$
|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|.
$$
Note, in addition, that
$$
|a - b| = |a + (-b)| \leq |a| + |-b| = |a| + |b|.
$$

To prove the reverse triangle inequality, we apply the preceding reasoning to the equations
\begin{align*}
b &= (a + b) - a & \text{obtaining}\quad |b| &\leq |a + b| + |a|, \\
a &= (a + b) - b & \text{obtaining}\quad |a| &\leq |a + b| + |b|.
\end{align*}
Rearranging the inequalities on the right, we have
$$
-|a + b| \leq |a| - |b| \leq |a + b|.
$$
This chain of inequalities is also of the form $-c \leq x \leq c$, this time with $x = |a| - |b|$ and $c = |a + b|$, and so can be "traded" for
$$
\bigl||a| - |b|\bigr| \leq |a + b|.
$$

Comment: I wish we could somehow "merge" our answers. I feel like yours picks up where mine left off and completes a comprehensive analysis. Very nice +1

Comment: @crash: Thanks. :) As I see it, MSE's purpose is to aggregate high quality answers to questions likely to be asked in the future. Even without merging, multiple answers to one question remain available to posterity, and that's what really matters in the long run.

Comment: I completely agree. Also, I like to think of the posterity as not being solely comprised of MSE users, which is why I wrote up [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184541/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-weak-and-strong-induction/1184785#1184785) ridiculously long answer. I oftentimes try to write answers with two things in mind: 1) Keep the OP's math level in mind, and 2) answer that so that your answer may be useful for all other users. It seems we think similarly. :)

Answer (score 2):

$a\le b$ means $a$ is less than or equal to $b$, so we have $3\le 3$ and $3\le 4$ for example, since $3$ is equal to $3$ and $3$ is less than $4$.

For example, $|2+5|=7=|2|+|5|$, so $|2+5|\le |2|+|5|$. And $|-1+5|=4<6=|-1|+|5|$, so $|-1+5|\le |-1|+|5|$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about the triangle equality for **real numbers**, and there is a hint:

When $ab\ge0$, show that $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$.
When $a<0<b$, show that $|a+b|<|b|<|a|+|b|$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convince yourself that the statement is true, then you should break the statement part into cases: both $a$ and $b$ are positive, both $a$ and $b$ are negative, one is positive and the other is negative, etc.

If you want to know why it is called the triangle inequality, pick any $x$. Let $y = x - a$ and $z = y - b$. Then we have that $a = x - y$ and $b = y - z$. Thus, the inequality becomes:
$$ |x - z| \le |x - y| + |y - z| $$

Now think of $x$, $y$, and $z$ as vertices of a triangle, and the absolute value as a distance function. Then the meaning is clear: the distance between $x$ and $z$ is shorter than the distance between $x$ and $z$ through the intermediate point $y$.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about signed values.

When $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, you always get the strict equality. When the sign differs, you get the inequality.

The given inequation summarizes these two situations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just triangular inequality in 1 dimension.

To proof it you square both side

There is a proof here already

[Proof of triangle inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307348/proof-of-triangle-inequality)

$$(a+b)^2= a^2+b^2+2a\cdot b \leq a^2+b^2+2\left| a \right| \left| b \right| $$
$$(a+b)^2 \leq \left(\left| a \right| + \left| b \right|\right)^2$$

And the triangular inequality follows.

What you need to watch is what is $a\cdot b$ That is a real number defined by a binary operation of 2 products. Basically one theorem of the dot product is that the dot product will never exceed the size multiple of the vectors. I got to find the proof here.

So basically

$a\cdot b \leq \left| a \right| \left| b \right|$

The value is the same only if the vectors are in the exact same direction.

Now extend that to one dimension and your vectors only have 2 directions. They can both point toward positive or negative real numbers.

If the direction the same, the inequality becomes equality. If the direction is not, then the inequality hold.

Answer (score -1):

$|x|$ means the absolute value of $x$. This means that if the value of $x<0$, then $|x|=-x$ otherwise $|x|=x$. In simple words, $|x|$ is formed by removing the minus sign from $x$, if any. So $|4|=4$ and $|-3|=3$

The equation states an obvious fact:
$$|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$$

If $a$ and $b$ are both positive, we have $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$, else we have $|a+b|<|a|+|b|$

Try putting these values, and you should be able to figuring it out: $(2,5)$, $(2,-5)$, $(-2,-5)$

What this has to do with a triangle is unclear to me, though.

Comment: The triangle comes from the fact that if one considers the metric induced by $|\cdot|$, then this is the triangle inequality. In particular, it means that the the distance of going from $a$ to $b$ is smaller than the distance of going from $a$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $b$. When you now draw a triangle in say $\mathbb{R}^2$ of corners $a,b,0$ then it states the obvious fact that the edge $a$ to $b$ is always smaller than the other two edges.

Comment: IMO, the given inequation is not the Triangle Inequality, but a lemma in the proof of $|a-b|\le|a-c|+|c-b|$.