# Proof of absolute inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I am new to proofs and would like some help understanding how to prove the following abs inequality.

$$| -x-y | \leq |x| + |y|.$$

I think I should take out the negative in the left absolute value function.? Then prove for the triangle inequailty.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: So, the left side would be |(-1)|*|x+y| => |x+y| then i just prove the triangle inequailty.

Comment: Yes. $\mid (-1) \mid$ equals $1$, so you get equality in your above comment. Then indeed use triangle inequality.

Comment: yes, but after removing the negative do i prove |x+y| <= |x| + |y| because that is the triangle inequality?

Comment: Exactly. Do you also want to prove the triangle inequality ?

Comment: if you dont mind can you show me the proof for this inequality, i am a little confused on what to do.

Answer (score 2):

$$|-x-y| \leq |x| + |y|\\
|-1(x+y)| \leq |x| + |y|\\
|x+y||-1|\leq |x| + |y|\\
1|x+y|\leq |x| + |y|\\
|x+y|\leq |x| + |y|
$$
I think that you can take it from here as long as you use the fact that $|x| = \max(x, -x)$

Comment: Please use [MathJax formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your answers in the future.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\mid -x-y\mid = \mid -(x+y) \mid = \mid x+y \mid \leq \mid x \mid + \mid y \mid$. For the least step we use the triangle inequality. Supposing you work in $\mathbb R$ look here for a proof: [Proof of triangle inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307348/proof-of-triangle-inequality).

Comment: oh wow, thanks guys. This was really straight forward. get rid of negative, then prove triangle ineqauilty.