# Clueless on how to prove $\|(a,b)\| \le |a|+|b|$

Tags: inequality, vectors, normed-spaces, absolute-value

Basically, the inequality says that the norm of a vector is always less than or equal to the sum of the absolute value of its components.

And I know that the norm is defined as:

$$\|(a,b)\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

and the absolute value as:

$$|a|=\sqrt{a^2}$$

But I don't know how to relate both equations and prove the inequality.

Comment: For a start: square the inequality.

Comment: Do you know the triangle inequality? If so, write $(a,b) = (a,0)+(0,b)$ and apply it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson No, that's not the same thing. Read the question.

Comment: @ClementC. I have read the question.  As far as I can tell, the asker is asking for a proof of the triangle inequality.  If you think that the asker is wanting something else, perhaps you or the asker could elucidate?  It is also worth noting that answers to the the linked question adequately answer this question, e.g. [hunminpark's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/307384/468350) is essentially identical to cansomeonehelpmeout's answer here.

Comment: @XanderHenderson No, the proof is similar to that of the triangle inequality, but this is not proving the same thing. The triangle inequality is about the norm of the sum of two vectors vs. the sum of the norms of the two vectors. This is about the (Euclidean) norm of a vector vs. the sum of absolute values of its components.

Comment: @ClementC. So, it's the triangle inequality as applied to the vectors $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Erm, yes. Which is what my first comment said, if you have a look at it. It's a direct *application* of the triangle inequality, but it is not the triangle inequality itself. Xander Handerson's comment states that "the asker is asking for a proof of the triangle inequality." This is not the case (although a proof that the Euclidean norm satisfies the triangle inequality is very similar to a direct proof of the OP's inequality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squaring gives:
$$
||(a,b)||\leq|a|+|b|\iff (||(a,b)||)^2\leq(|a|+|b|)^2\iff 0\leq 2|a||b|.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Can be proved by contradiction that way (absolute values are always non-negative)

Comment: @JavierPoncet Sure if that suits your style.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the *triangle inequality*: $\;(a,b)=(a,0)+(0,b)$, so
$$\|(a,b)\|\le\|(a,0)\|+\|(0,b)\|=|a|+|b|.$$

Comment: @ClementC.: Oh! yes. Fixed. Thanks for pointing it!