# How do you prove $|x-a|+|y-b|=|(x+y)-(a+b)|$

Tags: absolute-value

I tried to prove it like this:
$\sqrt{x-a}^2+\sqrt{y-b}^2=\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-a}^2+\sqrt{y-b}^2)^2}$
from this we can expand all the terms and end up with a messy sum that I suppose results in
 $|$(x+y)-(a+b)|
Is there more sophisticated and logical way of proving or should I say deriving this?

Comment: Focus on the properties of absolute values. $|a|=a$, where is $\pm a$.

Comment: You cannot; try with $a=b=0$ and $x=1, y=-1$. We have $|x−a|+|y−b|=|x|+|y|=2$ and $|(x+y)−(a+b)|=|(x+y)|=0$.

Comment: Perfection! @MauroALLEGRANZA . Inequality is possible only.

Comment: With $u=x-a$ and $v =y-b$ you have $|u| + |v| = |u+v|$ and that holds (for real numbers) *if and only if* $u$ and $v$ have the same sign (or one of them is zero).

Comment: I see now. This is only true for inequalities.
$|x−a|+|y−b|>=|(x+y)−(a+b)|$ Now I need to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $u=x-a$ and $v =y-b$ you have the triangle inequality 
$$
|(x+y) - (a+b)|  =|u+v| \le |u| + |v| = |x-a| + |y-b| \, .
$$

Equality holds (for real numbers) *if and only if* $uv \ge 0$, i.e. $x-a$ and $y-b$ have the same sign, or one of them is zero.

For various proofs of the triangle inequality for real numbers, see for example [Proof of triangle inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307348/42969) or [Triangle Inequality/Real Numbers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality/Real_Numbers).