# Triangle Inequation proof

Tags: analysis

I have to show for all x,y ∈ ℝ that ||x| - |y| ≤ |x-y|

I know that |x| = |x - y + y| ≤ |x - y|+|y|

Does it suffice to put in numbers now or how would I proof that?

Comment: From what you know. it is enough to transform your inequality slightly. You want $|x-y|$ alone on the right side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of triangle inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307348/proof-of-triangle-inequality)

Comment: Well it seems that you finished the exercice, just put $|y|$ on the left side of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

We use the fact that

$$a\le b \; and \; -a\le b \;\implies$$
$$-b\le a\le b \implies |a|\le |b|$$

So, as you wrote
$$|x|=|x-y+y|\le |x-y|+|y| \implies $$

$$|x|-|y|\le |x-y|$$
and by symetry,
$$|y|-|x|\le |x-y|$$

take $ a=|x|-|y|\; and \; b=|x-y|$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $|x| = |x - y + y| ≤ |x - y|+|y|$ so $|x|-|y| \leq |x-y|$

Also $|y| = |y-x+x| \leq |y-x|+|x|$
and by subtracting $|y-x|$ and $|y|$ from both sides one gets $-|x-y|=-|y-x| \leq |x|-|y|$

Since $-|x-y| \leq |x|-|y| \leq |x-y| $,$ ||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|$.